# Should it be an instance variable or a method variable in this example?

Tags: c#

In this example should the Serializer object be an instance variable or a method variable in the two methods? What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

```
public class CustomerHelper
{

    private  _Serializer;
    private JavaScriptSerializer Serializer {
        get 
        {
            if (_Serializer == null) {
                _Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            }
            return _Serializer;
        }


    public Customer GetJsonLog(Customer Cust)
    {
        return GetFromLog(Serializer.Searilize(Cust));
    }

    public void WriteToLog(Customer Cust)
    {
        SaveToLog(Serializer.Searilize(Cust));
    }
}
```

Edit - Ignore Thread Safety issues and assume that Seralizer object will be re-used.

Comment: I would more worried about essentially having two different ways of getting to the serialiser in your code - one that could throw a `NullReferenceException`.  Why not just initialise it in your constructor and do away with the `private Serialiser` property?

Comment: What it if that property is used only in those two different methods? That's why I was lazy loading it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being down voted. I thought it's a valid question.

Comment: downvoting is a bit of a nightmare on SO at the moment.  Don't worry about it

Comment: I would assume you're being downvoted as your question is subjective and not really a fit for SO. There is no *problem* here. That being said, which option it 'should' be depends *entirely* on what you want it to do. They have different behaviours. The most glaring being thread safety, and whether or not a serializer is 'reusable' (is it valid to call `.Serialize()` twice?).

Comment: I would prefer a public static serializer instance, but it really depends on the serializer itself.

Comment: @rob See my edit. I understand that my question is not perfect. But unless you tell me what is wrong with the question how can I improve it? Also I'm not sure if this is a subjective question. There are definitely good and bad practices in programming.

Comment: @user3587180 It's subjective in the fact that both approaches are valid in different circumstances. It's like asking whether you should use windows or linux for development. And again, there is no *problem* here, which is what SO is for. I would recommend other stack exchange sites, but since there is no goal here, it's impossible to give you an answer. You need to figure out what it is you need it to do, and *why*, before you can make a decision. Depending on your requirement, either one could be the correct decision. Neither is best in general

Comment: I understand why you would think it is subjective. But I asked this question to verify that the approach i'm taking is not wrong. I didn't know that both approaches were valid - i'm a beginner programmer. I tried googling it but couldn't find the answer. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @user3587180 There are other ways of doing _lazy loading_, that don't expose hazards in your code.  As **Hendry** states

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your use-case is. If the `CustomHelper` is long lived, meaning it will be kept around and re-used, then creating it as a Member Property (Lazy or not, or even a Field, doesn't matter), rather than a locally scoped method field is better. You'll only have to allocate the Serializer once, then re-use that instance.

Again though, it depends on your use-case. Imagine if you were instantiating something where the `WriteToLog` method mutated the state of `CustomHelper`, and it's `Serializer` property. Would you want that mutated `Serializer` property to be shared on all subsequent calls? If you want a fresh Serializer, then you'd just instance it in your method.

In your example, the `CustomHelper` is stateless, and I assume the `Serializer` is as well. If that is the case, then a problem doesn't exist. It is however something to keep in mind when making these kind of design decisions.

As a side-note, if the `CustomHelper` is long lived, I'd clean up the code a bit by removing the property and just use the private field. With it being long-lived, odds are the first time you instantiate the helper you'll use it. So instantiating the Serializer in the constructor won't really hurt. Even less so if you re-use the same `CustomHelper` instance on subsequent calls.